# Windows Forms designer and custom CodeDomSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, designer

I am currently putting together a prototype for a custom tab control we are trying to implement in c# for .Net 2.0. As the control itself works fine, we are now trying to integrate full design-time behaviour. This does include a custom CodeDomSerializer at a certain point to tell that the tabs have to be added as well. This does work fine now (after a longer process of trial and error).

But there is a problem left that seems to have to do with Deserialization. The designer code is created just fine and the designer looks just the same. But when I hit rebuild project, the forms designer sometimes show this error:

```
The variable 'piTabControl1' is either undeclared or was never assigned
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4008y84t(v=vs.80).aspx

The error does not appear every time, but it always happens when I have just added a new tab. The error points to this line:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.piTabControl1);
```

But I know that the variable is assigned, as this is in the code a few lines before:

```
this.piTabControl1 = new pdfforge.PdfCreator.Controls.PiTabControl();
```

The application also does compile and run with everything shown properly. If I close the Designer and reopen it, it is also shown without that error. So I suspect that there is something going wrong when Deserializing the code or updating the designer.

I have uploaded the full solution here, because it is just too much code to paste here:

http://www.chinery.de/dateien/TabControlTest.zip

To reproduce this in the project, you will first have to recompile the whole solution for the custom controls to be compiled. Then you can open Form1 and hit rebuild. If it does not produce the error, you can try adding or deleting tabs from the tab control.

I really don't have a clue how to approach this, because I can't tell the inner state of the Forms designer. I am very thankful for any hint. I can also add specific code snippets here if requested.

Comment: Hello, i was unable to reproduce the issue with VS2012. Which editor are you using?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: This is the kind of problem you'll have when exceptions are thrown at design time, especially on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Start up another instance of VS to debug the first one.

Comment: I am sorry that the answer took a while. I was not able to find any exceptions while debugging. At the same time I found that if I do not have the control source in the same project as the form I want to design, the strange exception does not appear. If it stayed like this, it would be ok for the current state of the prototype.